# Select * query considering all files in the directory - Shell script

Tags: sql, bash, shell, unix

I have a SQL query :

```sql
insert into table1 select * from table2
```

I have to execute this query via shell script which i'm doing in following way:

```bash
read -d '' QUERY <<EOF
insert into table1 select * from table2;
EOF
```

The if i do
`echo $QUERY` it prints all files in the directory and that's why this insert is failing. Is there a way i can still use * without shell referencing it to files within that directory?

Comment: Put it in double quotes: `echo "$QUERY"`

Comment: It must be a duplicate

Comment: put in quotes the first `EOF`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell globbing on `*` would be happening wherever you're using `$QUERY`.  Apply quotation marks to wherever you might be using `$QUERY`.

Better to simply pipe the SQL statement into mysql or whatever it is.

```
echo "insert into table1 select * from table2" | mysql
```